Rust slice affecting size optimisation for ARM
I am currently working on a project with binary size limits (for ARMv7 target in thumb mode).
and when I build such code
unsafe {
        for x in buffer_slice.get_unchecked_mut(2..) {
            *x+=0x42;
        }
}

I obtain such asm
   0:   b580        push    {r7, lr}
   2:   466f        mov r7, sp
   4:   f1b2 0c02   subs.w  ip, r2, #2
   8:   d00a        beq.n   0x20
   a:   f101 0e02   add.w   lr, r1, #2
   e:   f89e 3000   ldrb.w  r3, [lr]
  12:   f1bc 0c01   subs.w  ip, ip, #1
  16:   f103 0342   add.w   r3, r3, #66 @ 0x42
  1a:   f80e 3b01   strb.w  r3, [lr], #1
  1e:   d1f6        bne.n   0xe
  20:   f247 3341   movw    r3, #29505  @ 0x7341
  24:   f2c0 0301   movt    r3, #1
  28:   4798        blx r3
  2a:   2000        movs    r0, #0
  2c:   bd80        pop {r7, pc}

Which is quit short and good for me
But when I do an assignment I have a much bigger result
unsafe {
        for x in buffer_slice.get_unchecked_mut(2..) { // semi opti could be better if direct affectation opti pourri
            *x=0x42;
        }
    };

   0:   b5f0        push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
   2:   af03        add r7, sp, #12
   4:   f84d bd04   str.w   fp, [sp, #-4]!
   8:   460d        mov r5, r1
   a:   1e91        subs    r1, r2, #2
   c:   4614        mov r4, r2
   e:   4606        mov r6, r0
  10:   bf1e        ittt    ne
  12:   1ca8        addne   r0, r5, #2
  14:   2242        movne   r2, #66 @ 0x42
  16:   f000 f80c   blne    0x32
  1a:   f247 3341   movw    r3, #29505  @ 0x7341
  1e:   4630        mov r0, r6
  20:   f2c0 0301   movt    r3, #1
  24:   4629        mov r1, r5
  26:   4622        mov r2, r4
  28:   4798        blx r3
  2a:   2000        movs    r0, #0
  2c:   f85d bb04   ldr.w   fp, [sp], #4
  30:   bdf0        pop {r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}
  32:   b5d0        push    {r4, r6, r7, lr}
  34:   af02        add r7, sp, #8
  36:   2910        cmp r1, #16
  38:   d346        bcc.n   0xc8
  3a:   4243        negs    r3, r0
  3c:   f003 0c03   and.w   ip, r3, #3
  40:   eb00 030c   add.w   r3, r0, ip
  44:   4283        cmp r3, r0
  46:   d922        bls.n   0x8e
  48:   f1ac 0e01   sub.w   lr, ip, #1
  4c:   f1bc 0f00   cmp.w   ip, #0
  50:   d010        beq.n   0x74
  52:   4604        mov r4, r0
  54:   f1bc 0f01   cmp.w   ip, #1
  58:   f804 2b01   strb.w  r2, [r4], #1
  5c:   d006        beq.n   0x6c
  5e:   7042        strb    r2, [r0, #1]
  60:   f1bc 0f02   cmp.w   ip, #2
  64:   bf1a        itte    ne
  66:   7082        strbne  r2, [r0, #2]
  68:   1cc4        addne   r4, r0, #3
  6a:   1c84        addeq   r4, r0, #2
  6c:   f1be 0f03   cmp.w   lr, #3
  70:   d204        bcs.n   0x7c
  72:   e00c        b.n 0x8e
  74:   4604        mov r4, r0
  76:   f1be 0f03   cmp.w   lr, #3
  7a:   d308        bcc.n   0x8e
  7c:   1f20        subs    r0, r4, #4
  7e:   f800 2f04   strb.w  r2, [r0, #4]!
  82:   1d04        adds    r4, r0, #4
  84:   429c        cmp r4, r3
  86:   70c2        strb    r2, [r0, #3]
  88:   7082        strb    r2, [r0, #2]
  8a:   7042        strb    r2, [r0, #1]
  8c:   d1f7        bne.n   0x7e
  8e:   eba1 0c0c   sub.w   ip, r1, ip
  92:   f02c 0003   bic.w   r0, ip, #3
  96:   4418        add r0, r3
  98:   4283        cmp r3, r0
  9a:   d213        bcs.n   0xc4
  9c:   b2d1        uxtb    r1, r2
  9e:   f04f 3401   mov.w   r4, #16843009   @ 0x1010101
  a2:   4361        muls    r1, r4
  a4:   f843 1b04   str.w   r1, [r3], #4
  a8:   4283        cmp r3, r0
  aa:   d20b        bcs.n   0xc4
  ac:   f843 1b04   str.w   r1, [r3], #4
  b0:   4283        cmp r3, r0
  b2:   bf3c        itt cc
  b4:   f843 1b04   strcc.w r1, [r3], #4
  b8:   4283        cmpcc   r3, r0
  ba:   d203        bcs.n   0xc4
  bc:   f843 1b04   str.w   r1, [r3], #4
  c0:   4283        cmp r3, r0
  c2:   d3ef        bcc.n   0xa4
  c4:   f00c 0103   and.w   r1, ip, #3
  c8:   1843        adds    r3, r0, r1
  ca:   4298        cmp r0, r3
  cc:   d21f        bcs.n   0x10e
  ce:   f011 0c03   ands.w  ip, r1, #3
  d2:   f1a1 0101   sub.w   r1, r1, #1
  d6:   d00d        beq.n   0xf4
  d8:   4604        mov r4, r0
  da:   f1bc 0f01   cmp.w   ip, #1
  de:   f804 2b01   strb.w  r2, [r4], #1
  e2:   d008        beq.n   0xf6
  e4:   7042        strb    r2, [r0, #1]
  e6:   f1bc 0f02   cmp.w   ip, #2
  ea:   bf1a        itte    ne
  ec:   7082        strbne  r2, [r0, #2]
  ee:   1cc4        addne   r4, r0, #3
  f0:   1c84        addeq   r4, r0, #2
  f2:   e000        b.n 0xf6
  f4:   4604        mov r4, r0
  f6:   2903        cmp r1, #3
  f8:   bf38        it  cc
  fa:   bdd0        popcc   {r4, r6, r7, pc}
  fc:   1f20        subs    r0, r4, #4
  fe:   f800 2f04   strb.w  r2, [r0, #4]!
 102:   1d01        adds    r1, r0, #4
 104:   4299        cmp r1, r3
 106:   70c2        strb    r2, [r0, #3]
 108:   7082        strb    r2, [r0, #2]
 10a:   7042        strb    r2, [r0, #1]
 10c:   d1f7        bne.n   0xfe
 10e:   bdd0        pop {r4, r6, r7, pc}

So is there a way to get a binary a bit more optimized for the size?

Are you compiling with optimization for size?  Clang has -Os (size and speed) and -Oz (size only, even when it hurts speed).  There should be equivalent options for rustc.  Also, what -mcpu?  Isn't the second code with just = basically a memset?

Also, where are the branch targets and labels within that longer disassembly? It's hard to follow and see what it's doing with just raw disassembly.  If you can link it on https://godbolt.org/, that makes it easy to see labels and try different compiler options.

Yes a memset like, but not the best onee for my use case
The main idea there is to do a shellcode, the assembly come from an objdump
I am using the optimisation level opt-level = "s (from cargo)
Thanks, I will take a look on godbot

I just find a way which don 't apply the memset optimization
for i in 2..buffer_size {
    ptr::write_volatile(buffer.offset(i as isize),0x42); // opti memset not apply
}

Reduce bin size to 0x2a
